# print "õüäö" with Epson TM-U220 Dot Matrix Printer using font substitution from HTML page

Tags: css, printing, character-encoding, epson

I have php generated lists of items wich i need to print out with Epson TM-U220PD dot matrix printer. Those lists have "õüäö" in them witch won't show up on the paper. I have tryed many encodings and different printer-fonts to substitude them with but with no success. Either õüäö won't show up or the whole text turns into something like this : "as1kj%fasw#jda&slkjd".

I need to use substitution, because i won't get 32+ characters/line with non-printer fonts.

I'm using:

- Windows XP pro 32 bit
- Install Version APD Ver4.10
- EPSON TM-U220 ReceiptE4 Version 5, 0, 7, 0
- EPSON Status API Version 4, 3, 9, 0
- firefox 4
- substitude FontB[255] from printer menu

any ideas?

thank you! I really am desperate here :D

http://pos.epson.com/products/TM-U220Series.htm

Comment: btw. If i use Arial, font11 and "Western" in wordpad, it works!